# To design a button in Wpf like google search icon

Tags: wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I'm trying to design a button and below is my code, but here the background is coming white and on click button border is highlighted, but what i'm trying is to design is a button like google search button, or like bookmark icon in search browser, in that button shape is like the icon and no border is shown on click ,

```
 <Button Name="LoadDllButton"  Margin="46,10,414,6" Width="41" >
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
        <Image  Source='\RibbonImages\search.png' Width="58" Height="18" />
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
</Button.ContentTemplate>
   </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the background, border brush and foreground to null or transparent. I inserted it in your code.

```
<Button Name="LoadDllButton" Margin="46,10,414,6" Width="41" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" >
<Button.ContentTemplate>
<ItemContainerTemplate>
    <Image  Source='\RibbonImages\search.png' Width="58" Height="18" />
</ItemContainerTemplate>
</Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for fast respose,

Comment: Thank you for fast response,  but  i have tried by setting these property to transparent. In this the problem is, inintially only search icon is visible but as we click on the button..the border of button is visible, which i dnt want.